# How can I power Raspberry Pi Zero / 3B in forest where I don't have enough sun?

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, ups, power-generation

I'm making an authonomous robot (like Phoenix probe but very simple and cheap and made for Earth, no moving parts, just sensors). It controlled by Raspberry Pi and will live in forest shadowed by trees. So, I guess I can't use the solar panel in this case (or that panel will be extremely huge).

Also, I don't want that my robot sleep during charging. Ideally, if it can record data 24/7.

I need at least 10W output for RPi powering and some additional power for battery charging (for situations when generator can't produce energy).

Which types of generators are available that can produce needed power, silent and compact enough (I don't want to bring petrol generator to forest). Also, I don't want to go to forest often to replace discharged batteries.

And I don't have any rivers and don't have powerful wind here.

I want to record video and audio (when motion is detected), and ideally run OpenCV and TFLite to recognize birds and animals.

Is it possible? Can I found a way to power it for at least a week without human interaction?

Comment: If it has no moving parts, it could maybe be redesigned to use 10x to 1000x less power. Then you would have no issue finding a big enough battery, or even running off a small solar panel.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi is a poor choice for a low-power application. The Texas Instruments MSP430 series of MCUs is designed for low-power applications, there are also others.

Comment: A "robot" with "no moving parts, just sensors" is not a robot... It's a sensor.

Comment: @brhans It's a science station, ok? Like devices on Mars and Venus.

Comment: Is it possible that you can take a solar panel out to the forest and measure how much power you actually do get?

Comment: I used small foldable panel (like paper A4 size) which gives 5V 0.2A at direct sun. It gave me nothing at that conditions.

I need at least 20W of power generation to power the RPi and charge the batteries for night work. So, needed panel will be big and expensive.

Comment: Why is it using a power hungry Raspberry Pi? What does the sensor do if it requires so much computing power it needs a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: People have generated electric power from sound, but this would also probably be too big.

Comment: One advantage from generating electric power from sound is you could also use it for a sensor.

Comment: May be best to just calculate the total watt hours you need for a week then select a deep cycle LA battery to match the requirement.  Then when you service the unit swap out the battery with a freshly charged one.  Use a high efficiency voltage regulator for the system and try to use some of the power saving tips presented in the other comments, especially the power down and sleep mode.

Comment: Is there a plant in the location that could be used as a power source?  See https://agris.fao.org/agris-search/search.do?recordID=US201700105022  living banana plant as a long-lasting battery cell

Comment: @PerryWebb there are a lot of trees :)

Comment: You might also be able to use the ground.  See https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Make-a-Microbial-Fuel-Cell-MFC-Using-Mud/

Comment: @PerryWebb There is no way to extract enough power from sound to power something like a Raspberry Pi. It's for "energy harvesting" applications where you only need the tiniest trickle of free energy (think those Amazon ordering buttons)

Comment: I would put a sensor without the video processing in the forest to just measure how often it is triggered, so you can find out the amount of high power processing your full version will have to do. If it only runs 10% of the time, your battery charging current is down to 1/10th, etc.

Comment: Are there many small rodents in the vicinity? You could find out how much power you can get from a hamster wheel: [free wild mice will run on wheels installed in the field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamster_wheel).

Answer (score 3):

Redesign it with a low-power bare-metal microcontroller. Many microcontrollers use something like 0.05W when active, and 0.00001W when in deep-sleep mode. Then, you can easily power the device with a solar panel even though limited light is available.

Your code needs to conserve power by using the microcontroller's sleep mode as much as possible. For example, if you only want to measure every 5 seconds, the microcontroller should sleep for 4.9 seconds and then use 0.1 seconds to perform the measurement.

I suspect that downgrading to a microcontroller will give you plenty of power even if you leave it running all the time, so you won't need to be too fussy about sleeping.

---

You indicated you need to do some video processing which really does need the computing power of the Raspberry Pi. Your main goal is still to decrease power consumption as much as possible, but you can't do it by just downgrading the computer. You need the Pi to sleep as much as possible. If it's running Linux, this is probably quite difficult, because Linux will take several seconds to go to sleep and to wake up, unlike a microcontroller that takes a few milliseconds, and this severely limits your ability to make it sleep much.

You could try underclocking and undervolting it.

You could try using a low-powered device (such as a PIR sensor or Arducam) to watch for movement and wake up the Pi when it detects some.

You could do the video processing in batches - with a low-power device recording video all the time (or when there's movement), and a high-power device running every now and again to process the recorded data.

In fact, do you really need to do the processing in the field at all? What if you bring the memory card back home after a week, and then do the video processing on your own computer? If you choose that route, you may find it better to use an off-the-shelf motion-activated video camera, instead of making your own.

Comment: But I want to record video and audio (when motion is detected), and ideally run the OpenCV and TFLite to recognize birds and animals. What low power microcontroller can offer this to me.

The ideal variant that I found is Orange Pi i96. Maybe, I can downclock the CPU to save some power.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I can use a pair of Raspberry Pi Pico and Orange Pi i96.

Comment: @Robotex okay, then it might not be so simple - processing video does need some processing power. Though I would consider whether you could perhaps use a PIR (passive infrared) motion sensor to activate the Pi.

Comment: @Robotex I would guess that all of the Raspberry-Pi-style boards use about the same amount of power. But they might have different power-saving abilities. Like maybe one of them makes it easier to turn off the camera.

Comment: But maybe some powerful generators exist? For i.e. hydrogen power cells or alcohol power cells?

Comment: For i.e. I can have two cameras: Arducam and USB web-cam. web cam turnung on only when arducam detects motion.

Comment: Yes, that is an idea. Pretty much, do everything you can to save power, and then there is a good chance you might have enough power. If that works, the question is solved... otherwise, it's not solved and more ideas are needed.

Comment: I used infrared sensor: the object leaves camera frame before camera starts recording.

Comment: From here https://www.pidramble.com/wiki/benchmarks/power-consumption I see that Pi Zero consume around 0.1A. So, I need a 35Ah battery for a week, right?

Comment: @Robotex I updated the answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: @Robotex There are 168 hours in a week so a 16.8Ah 5V battery will work, in theory. If the battery is more or less voltage (and you have a buck or boost converter) it will need less or more Ah. (e.g. 7Ah x 12V, but add a bit more to account for converter efficiency loss). I happen to be a fan of SLA batteries if the weight is okay; a 9Ah 12V SLA battery costs about $30-50 and weighs about 2kg; lithium batteries are lighter and smaller but also more expensive and made with slave labour.

Comment: I can use a gravity generator.

Comment: @Robotex neat idea, but 15 watt-seconds means lifting 1.5kg up by 1 meter. If you have 500kg and you lift it 50 meters (unrealistically big numbers) you can power 15W for about four and a half hours. Your focus is still on reducing power. The 0.5W Pi Zero would last for about five and a half *days* with the same (unrealistically big) gravity battery

Comment: Meanwhile a $100 lead-acid battery and a buck converter will power your 0.5W for a week or two, no problem. No need to lift 500kg weights.

Answer (score 1):

Raise a solar panel to the top of a tree?

If you have wind, use the movement of the branches to drive a ratchet system connected to them with rope to spin a generator with each stroke

Comment: that seems complicated compared to a windmill

Comment: Will the windmill work in forest (I don't sure that wind will be strong enough here)? Is the windmills which can give you 50W of power 12 hours a day exist?

Comment: no idea, sorry.

Comment: @user253751 Solutions probably depend on you getting to the tree tops, unless you have some handy geothermal sources about

Comment: Can I use sugar from trees juice to generate power?

Comment: @Robotex That's a research project of its own. You're getting fanciful here.